# One Websocket Server with multiple client (app)

Tags: java, android, sockets

In my current android application I have started one Websocket Server. My concern is that Is it possible with only one websocket Server with multiple open connections from the same client (app) and/or the same device? It would be great if anyone have running code snippet for the same problem.

TIA.

Comment: Why are you running a websocket server inside your app?  A client going to a remote server I would get.  A server-  if you're serving data to your own app, there's better ways.  If you're serving data to other apps on the same device, there's probably better ways, plus how are you going to insure that your app stays resident?  A websocket server makes no sense on a mobile device.

Comment: The application having websocket server is intermediary application, which can handle  browser application request and perform operation on device and return results of the operation back to browser app. Also my android app having a foreground service which is continuously running .

Comment: An app should not cooperate with a browser in such a way. For few things requires webpage, use a web view. AND there's no limit on how many clients for a server..

Comment: Basically the app has to push asynchronous events like scanner codes via websocket server to a browser.